# Echart tooltip with a hyper link

Tags: echarts

I am trying to put a clickable hyper link on echart tooltip.

```
  tooltip: {
    appendToBody: true,
    hideDelay: 3000,
    formatter: function (o) { return "<a href="http://google.com">test</a>" ; }
  }
```

Tooltip is rendered with underlined test text, but the link doesn't work (it is not clickable).

SVG/Canvas driver doesn't make situation better.
Echart version is 5.4.2

Comment: Same problem here with echarts@5.4.3...

Answer (score 1):

frist, you must use HTTPS, and then you can check tooltip css attribute. it have  pointer-events: none. you can chanel it.
you can use

```
 tooltip: {
   appendToBody: true,
   hideDelay: 3000,
   extraCssText: 'pointer-events: auto!important',
   formatter: function (o) { return "<a href="https://google.com">test</a>" ;}
}
```

Comment: I also had to add `showDelay: 1000,` otherwise it dissapeared to quickly.